# Django : Dynamically update results page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a python code which starts running on a button click. This function takes some time to complete. In my django code, the result page is displayed after this function has completed execution.

But what I want is some sort of queue based mechanism using which my currently running function can pass the partial results (list of links) as it computes it, to the views and the result page contents are updated dynamically according to data in the queue so that the user won't have to wait for the whole function to finish exception  and can see partial results on the result page.

I am new to django and web development. How can this be done in django? Is there any library for doing this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the partial computation in a function synchronous way. You can try to consider this library [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to do the asynchronous execution.

OR ELSE

You have to go with intermediate middleware where Python and Javascript can be communicated in thread safe way like  redis queue, [zmq](http://zeromq.org/) etc..

Answer (score 0):

Ajax would be more appropriate to do this kind of "real time" updates. It allows you to send asynchronous (the A of AJAX) requests/datas.

Put a script in your web page that will update the render everytime your server send new datas.

You can find more on this here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/